# Add more than one foreign key between two tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been working on a local Sports Fantasy app. The app allows each team to include 8 players where a player can be in more than one team. I've created a table inside the database for player's information and another table for team's information. I want a way to connect a `team` row to multiple `player` rows.

My current code:

```py
class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32), index=True, nullable=False)
    price = Column(Integer)
    position = Column(String(32))
    picture = Column(String(32), index=True)

class PlayerStatus(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player_status'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    player_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    round = Column(Integer)
    goals = Column(Integer, default=0)
    assists = Column(Integer, default=0)
    clean_sheet = Column(Integer, default=0)
    saves = Column(Integer, default=0)
    bonus = Column(Integer, default=0)
    minutes_played = Column(Integer, default=0)
    goals_conceded = Column(Integer, default=0)
    player = relationship(Player)

class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    gk_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    defender_1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    defender_2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    mid_1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    mid_2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    mid_3_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    attack_1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    attack_2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    total_points = Column(Integer)

    player = relationship(Player)
    user = relationship(User)
```

Comment: What is your problem? Is there an error?

Comment: The database is still incomplete but I still can't understand how it would work.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem you're having is the `player = relationship(Player)`?